# jQuery - How to add image when radio button checked for separate radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the below to display a checkmark image in each of the 'select-check' divs when a user selects a radio button within the two cards.

Right now, when a user clicks, both cards display a checkmark. I tried using jQuery parent() but it wouldn't allow me to move the checkmark to a spot I wanted to.

Any info would be great!

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/93121/

JQUERY:

```
$("input:radio").on('click', function () {
   if($('input:radio').is(':checked')) {
     $(this).addClass("select-check");
     $(".select-check").css("display", "");
    } else {
      $(".select-check").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <li class="mix" style="display: inline-block;" data-bound="">
              <div class="select-check" style="display:none;"></div>
              <div class="card card-eight card--resource not-visible"> <!--Resource-->

                   <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">Card One</div>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="f-option1" name="selector-one" value="add1">
                              <label for="f-option1">Select 1</label>
                              <div class="check" style="top:60px;"><div class="inside">Add</div></div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="s-option1" name="selector-one" value="add2">
                              <label for="s-option1">Select 2</label>
                              <div class="check" style="top:100px;"><div class="inside">Add</div></div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="t-option1" name="selector-one" value="add3">
                              <label for="t-option1">Select 3</label>

                              <div class="check" style="top:140px;"><div class="inside">Add</div></div>
                            </li>
                      </ul>

                   </div>
              </div>
    </li>


    <li class="mix" style="display: inline-block;" data-bound="">
              <div class="select-check" style="display:none; top: 380px;"></div>
              <div class="card card-nine card--resource not-visible"> <!--Resource-->

                   <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">Card 2</div>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="f-option2" name="selector-two" value="add1">
                              <label for="f-option2">Select 1</label>
                              <div class="check" style="top:60px;"><div class="inside">Add</div></div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="s-option2" name="selector-two" value="add2">
                              <label for="s-option2">Select 2</label>
                              <div class="check" style="top:100px;"><div class="inside">Add</div></div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="t-option2" name="selector-two" value="add3">
                              <label for="t-option2">Select 3</label>

                              <div class="check" style="top:140px;"><div class="inside">Add</div></div>
                            </li>

                      </ul>
                   </div>
              </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do but try this function (with comments) to see if this get you closer to where you want to go.

```
$("input:radio").on("click", function () {
    // Get the <li> containing this card and show
    // $(this) here refers to the clicked radio
    var container = $(this).closest("li.mix");
    // Display container first element .select-check
    container.find(".select-check:first").show();
    // Remove class "select-check" from each radio in container
    // (Not sure why you're using the same class for this)
    $.each(container.find("input:radio"), function () {
        // $(this) here in the loop refers to the individual radio element
        $(this).removeClass("select-check");
    });
    // Add class "select-check" to the selected radio
    $(this).addClass("select-check");
});
```

Hopefully the logic will allow you to modify things if it's not quite what you're after.

(and I know it's a work in progress, but I think the `css` needs a bit more work. Using `position:absolute` with a fixed top can lead to problems with different screen sizes).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfect! Really appreciate the help.